# Render uniform distance between buttons in a div?

Tags: html, rendering, alignment

I don't know the rendered width of DIV or any of the buttons.  How do I change the markup such that the buttons are rendered with a uniform (or as close as can be) distance between each of them?

**EDIT:** Also, the buttons should consume the full width of the DIV.

```
<div>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Action1" />
    <!-- space between rendered buttons -->
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Action2" />
    <!-- space between rendered buttons -->
    <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Action3" />
    <!-- space between rendered buttons -->
    <asp:Button ID="Button4" runat="server" Text="Action4" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am *thinking* this can't be done without a table, JavaScript or the use of at least some (relative) widths (if you can set percentages, it's easy.).

Or maybe putting each button into a div with `display: table-cell`, but I find that sick. Then rather be honest and use a table.

Feel free to prove me wrong, I'd be interested in alternative approaches myself.

Comment: Marking this as the answer for now.  Here's to someone coming along later and offering us both an alternative.